# Saling files hosted on Amazon S3

Tags: 7, commerce

I am trying to set Drupal 7, Drupal Commerce and Amazon to be able to sale files that are already on Amazon s3 servers.
I have set all of the settings, including the services key and the secret key in the AWS module.

It seems that everything was set just fine, but I don't find the way to connect a file to a product. I don't even find a list of files from my Amazon socket.

Does someone has an experience with selling files with Drupal Commerce 7.x-2.x?

Comment: You need commerce_file 2.x and the amazons3 module.
Referencing existing S3 files from a filefield is a support request for amazons3. This issue might be relevant: https://drupal.org/node/1277152

Comment: I have set everything just fine (It recognize my socket - Doesn't have any error), But I didn't figure out how to set an existing file inside licence product (In the commerce_file 2.X)?